# Azure Kusto create database with KQL

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

Is it possible to create a database with KQL?

I don't see this option under [Databases management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/databases) in the documentation.

I know I can create a DB with SDKs/CLI, but I'm working with Kusto a lot and it would be great if I found this option.

My scenario is - database for end to end tests and general playground (not production stuff).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this option is available only through the SDK.